# Select specific columns from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an efficient way to `drop` `n` number of `columns` from a `pandas df`. For example, if you don't want anything past a certain column can you incorporate a function `df.drop > n`

For the df below I want to drop everything past `column 2`. I doing this via.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    '1' : ['X','Y'],  
    '2' : ['A','B'], 
    '3' : ['C','D'],   
    '4' : ['A','B'], 
    '5' : ['C','D'], 
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.drop(['3','4','5'], axis = 1)
```

But if there are more or less than `5 columns` I would have to manually add or subtract the `column values`. If I'm constantly doing this it becomes cumbersome.

Comment: `df=df.iloc[:,:4]`, will keep colummns, 0,1,2,3

Comment: `df.iloc[:,:n]` will drop everything after n columns. If the number of columns is less than `n` then no error will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use df.iloc,

```
df=df.iloc[:,:3] #sliced based on indices. will keeps columns 0 to 2 (indices).
(or)
df=df.loc[:,:'3'] #sliced based on column names
print(df)
1   2   3
X   A   C
Y   B   D
```